# Why can't i delete an empty app service plan?

Tags: azure

When i try to delete an empty app service plan in get the following error:
Storage usage quota exceeded. Cannot update or delete a server farm.

I tried it during the last couple of days from various browsers and pc's.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue in the past, and it looks like that it happens when you hit [web app plan storage limits](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/) somehow. I was able to resolve that after a few days and changing the plan from a Free (i think, or it was Shared, i do not remember already) to Standard.